# where do I inject the <strong> tag in this PHP code to make the $key output in bold letters?

Tags: php

I've been going back and forth trying to figure out where to put the  tags in this code and nothing seems to be working.

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors','on'); ?><?php


$data= "";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data.= str_replace("_"," ",$key).":\n\n ". $value."\n\n\n\n"; preg_replace("/[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]/", "_", $value);
}


$fileName= fopen("Submissions/".$_POST['First_Name'],'w');

fwrite($fileName, $data);
fclose($fileName);

$body= "You have a new submission";
$from = 'From: A_New_Client';
$to = 'myemail.com';
$subject = 'A New Questionnaire';

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])||($_POST['submit'])) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your questionnaire has been submitted!  You will be contacted with further assistance once everything is reviewed.</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
}

?>
```

The only place where dreamweaver didn't show up red was when I put it on the $key in the string replace, but it printed out with the tags rather than being bold.  Do I need to create a new variable or something to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data.= "<strong>".str_replace("_"," ",$key). "</strong> :\n\n ". $value."\n\n\n\n"; preg_replace("/[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]/", "_", $value);
}
```

Comment: when I do it this way the strong tags get printed out in the saved file.

Comment: You cannot directly apply styles to your normal txt and .doc files..But output the value into .html file then you will get the result ... See the code " $fileName= fopen("Submissions/".$_POST['First_Name'].'.html','w'); "